# Memory Leak with Phonegap Cordova Web Audio

Tags: ios, cordova, memory-leaks, web-audio-api

I've seen this question asked here already : [Web Audio API Memory Leaks on Mobile Platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119684/web-audio-api-memory-leaks-on-mobile-platforms)  but there doesn't seem to be any response to it.  I've tried lots of different variations - setting variables to null once I'm finished with them, or declaring the variables within scope, but it appears that the AudioContext (or OfflineAudioContext ) is not being Garbage collected after each operation.  I'm using this with Phonegap, on an IOS, so the browser is safari.  Any ideas how to solve this memory leak?

Here is my code:

```
function readVocalsToBuffer(file){
    console.log('readVocalsToBuffer');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt){
        var x = audioContext.decodeAudioData(evt.target._result, function(buffer){
            if(!buffer){
                console.log('error decoding file to Audio Buffer');
                return;
            }
            window.voiceBuffer = buffer;
            loadBuffers();
        });
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

function loadBuffers(){
    console.log('loadBuffers');
    try{
        var bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
            audioContext,
            [
                "."+window.srcSong
            ],
            createOffLineContext
        );
        bufferLoader.load()
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}

function createOffLineContext(bufferList){
    console.log('createOfflineContext');
    offline = new webkitOfflineAudioContext(2, window.voiceBuffer.length, 44100);
    var vocalSource = offline.createBufferSource();
    vocalSource.buffer = window.voiceBuffer;
    vocalSource.connect(offline.destination);

    var backing = offline.createBufferSource();
    backing.buffer = bufferList[0];
    backing.connect(offline.destination);

    vocalSource.start(0);
    backing.start(0);

    offline.oncomplete = function(ev){
        vocalSource.stop(0);
        backing.stop(0);
        vocalSource.disconnect(0);
        backing.disconnect(0);
        delete vocalSource;
        delete backing;
        delete window.voiceBuffer;
        window.renderedFile = ev.renderedBuffer;
        var bufferR = ev.renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        var bufferL = ev.renderedBuffer.getChannelData(1);
        var interleaved = interleave(bufferL, bufferR);
        var dataview = encodeWAV(interleaved);
        window.audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], {type: 'Wav'});
        saveFile();
    }

    offline.startRendering();

}

function interleave(inputL, inputR){
    console.log('interleave');
    var length = inputL.length + inputR.length;
    var result = new Float32Array(length);

    var index = 0,
        inputIndex = 0;

    while (index < length){
        result[index++] = inputL[inputIndex];
        result[index++] = inputR[inputIndex];
        inputIndex++;
    }
    return result;
}

function saveFile(){
    offline = null;
    console.log('saveFile');
    delete window.renderedFile;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, fail);
}
```

Comment: I just left an answer on the other question that you linked. Maybe that'll help explain the memory usage to some extent.

Comment: Hi Thanks Kevin.  Yes I understand your logic for that answer. I've tried setting the AudioContext to null and the OfflineAudioContext to null once I've finished with them, and I can see that some of the memory is being released, but I'm still gaining about 30MB each time.  I'm thinking that maybe there might be some order to destroying the objects that I'm not getting right.  ie.  disconnect the buffer first, then destroy the buffer, then destroy the Context.  other than that I'm at a loss.....