# Do browsers limit the number of decodeAudioData calls per session?

Tags: web-audio-api

I have a React Next web app that plays songs using web audio api. I noticed that after browsing a lot of songs, at some point my app won't load new songs.

In Chrome I get this error:
*Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data*,
and only after refreshing the page (sometimes need to refresh 2-3 times), I can load songs again.
Looking at "Total JS heap size" in the Memory tab in Chrome devtools doesn't indicate a memory leak.

In Safari it just refreshes the page automatically.

To make sure it's not something in my code, I made a new web app with a minimal example, and I could reproduce the issue. I get the decoding error after ~250 times.

```
export const test = async () => {
  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const blob = (
    await axios.get("./url-to-some-song.wav", {
      responseType: "blob",
    })
  ).data;

  for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
  }
};
```

I tried to add a delay after every iteration - it doesn't help.
It looks like browsers may have some limits, but I couldn't find any documentation for that.
What could it be?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464571/is-there-a-way-to-stop-web-audio-api-decodeaudiodata-method-memory-leak?rq=2

but calling audioContext.close() doesn't help

Comment: Tried to reproduce it, but it doesn't seem like giving any error. Also, the heap size didn't exceeded 9MB throughout

Comment: @Chinz Maybe try with 1000 instead of 300?

Comment: It's still the same

Comment: Well, it happens to me. Also I notice the same thing on Spotify web - I click "next" again anf again, just starting to hear the first second of each song. At some point, after about 200 songs, it will start failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem in Chrome v122. It seems to be fixed when using `structuredClone()`. But I don't have a good explanation why that works. I guess it's a bug in Chrome.

```js
export const test = async () => {
  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const blob = (
    await axios.get("./url-to-some-song.wav", {
      responseType: "blob",
    })
  ).data;

  for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(
      structuredClone(arrayBuffer)
    );
  }
};
```

You could also avoid the additional step by getting the data as `'arrayBuffer'` directly.

```js
export const test = async () => {
  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const arrayBuffer = (
    await axios.get("./url-to-some-song.wav", {
      responseType: "arrayBuffer",
    })
  ).data;

  for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(
      structuredClone(arrayBuffer)
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok, super interesting! I need to read more about it, but at first glance it does seem related: the original problem is probably that the browser doesn't release memory on decodeAudioData. structuredClone and transferrable objects are about memory sharing, so I see how it might be related.
Anyway, I could get it to work with the minimal example but doesn't work in my actual app, not sure yet why.
In the minimal example, try to add console.log(audioBuffer) at the end of the for loop - it will make it stop working for some reason. So doing stuff with the audio buffer might break the solution.

Comment: I can imagine a `console.log(audioBuffer)` prevents the garbage collection of that `audioBuffer` since it needs to be accessible for inspection in the console.

Comment: I don't see why it would prevent GC completely. Also, the js heap memory does not grow. Maybe it delays GC though. It seems like a relevant point. In my real React app I keep some audio buffers in an object that is garbage collected when some component unmounts. What helped is doing the structuredClone (or instead calling arrayBuffer.transfer() before passing to decodeAudioData), but also I needed to explicitly set the audioBuffer references to null, perhaps to trigger GC to work faster. It all seems to fix the issue. I just don't understand how structuredClone is related and how GC is related

Comment: also related:
https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1175